# What's so special in web sockets messages displayed with a green background in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

Looking at web sockets at Stack Exchange, I notice that some messages are displayed with a green background in Chrome:

[image: A screenshot of Network tab of Developer tools, showing messages with green background among ordinary messages with white background]

What's so special in those messages? What are they?

Comment: 7 years later, now I see arrows: orange, black and green, no idea what they are...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The green background ones are frames (messages) sent to the server. The white background are the ones received from the server.

> Messages are color-coded according to their type:
>
> - Outgoing text messages are light-green.
> - Incoming text messages are white.
> - WebSocket opcodes are light-yellow.
> - Errors are light-red.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#frames)